# Why are there two sets of the Ctrl, Alt, and Shift modifier keys on the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

Why are there two sets of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier keys when only one of each is necessary?

Comment: Do you only have one hand?

Comment: As a member of the sinistral minority, I appreciate *not having* to use my right hand for everything.

Comment: The two `ALT` keys are actually different, with the `ALTGr` key usually the same as pressing `CTRL+ALT`.

Comment: Several questions are marked as duplicate of this question. This should be re-opened or the others marked as closed for a better reason.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When touch-typing, you use the alternate side "function" keys.

E.g.

qwer,asdf,zxcv you'd use the right shift with your right hand without needing to stretch your left hand while pressing one of the aforementioned keys.

Comment: Ergonomics FTW.

Comment: The **1, 2, 3, 4, 5, T, G, and B** keys (plus a few others) are missing from that list -- these should also be used in conjunction with modifier keys on the right-hand side of the keyboard.

Comment: I figured Prasanth knew what I meant. I'll be sure to define myself more thoroughly next time.

Answer (score 8):

These modifier keys are very important for professional typists.  If there was only one modifier key for CTRL, Alt, and Shift, then typing speed could be slowed down when one of these modifier keys was needed.

There is a concept of a "dividing line" which is supposed to be like this (and can be seen in the coloured keyboard image included below which comes from an instructional typing program which was probably designed for children):

- For the **Right-Shift key** all the keys on the left up to:  **5, T, G, and B**
- For the **Left-Shift key** all the keys on the right starting from:  **6, Y, H, and N**

(The same usage applies for the CTRL and Alt modifier keys.)

Unfortunately function keys are a bit of a mess depending on how the keyboard manufacturer designed the spacing, but traditionally they're grouped in three groups of 4 keys with F1, F2, F3 and F4 on the left-hand side, and F5 through F12 on the right-hand side, of the dividing line.

[image]

Comment: I agree in the regard of Shift keys, but I disagree in the regard of Alt. It seems that Alt is designed to be pressed with a thumb, so pressing it does not block other fingers from pressing other keys. I like that the right Alt is often used to input more symbols instead of redundancy. I don't know about Ctrl. I press the right Ctrl with the side of my palm, which, again, does not block my fingers from pressing keys. So the right Ctrl is useless for me, but it seems obvious to me that this is not a design intention.