# What is the purpose of the right Windows key?

Tags: keyboard, windows-key

[image]

> The Windows key is found between the Alt keys and Ctrl keys on both
>   sides of the spacebar. With some keyboard manufacturers they may
>   substitute the Windows logo for another picture, but they key still
>   functions the same.

Why do keyboards commonly have *two* Windows keys?

Comment: Same as right Ctrl, right Alt (non-Gr), and right Shift, I would guess.

Comment: @grawity: On my keyboard [SteelSeries Apex Raw](https://i.imgur.com/rqTKVVh.jpg) the key does nothing.

Comment: Either it's broken or the driver is broken. Normally LWin and RWin would have identical functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are there two sets of the CTRL, Alt, and Shift modifier keys on the keyboard?](http://superuser.com/questions/304295/why-are-there-two-sets-of-the-ctrl-alt-and-shift-modifier-keys-on-the-keyboard), [Why does a keyboard have two Ctrl keys?](http://superuser.com/questions/466796/why-does-a-keyboard-have-two-ctrl-keys?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: I'm not sure if this post is technically a duplicate since that one doesn't mention the Windows key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For convenience sake, so you can use either hand to access it.

Comment: Wrong. They don't do the same things.

Comment: @Tonny You're confusing Windows key with the menu key.

Comment: @DavidPostill In all my 35 years of using computers I have never seen, or even heard of, a keyboard having 2 Windows keys. I have seen plenty of keyboards with the right-key (menu-key) labeled as a 2nd Windows-key. Seems they do exist, but I honestly didn't think so and assumed teh poster was confused.

Answer (score -2):

They don't do the same things.
In a default standard Windows setup the left-key opens the Start-menu and is used in various combinations (E.g left-WIndows-key+R open the Run-prompt) as short-cut key.
The right Windows-key functions the same as the right mouse-button key on your mouse.

EDIT:
In all my 35 years of using computers I have never seen, or even heard of, a keyboard having 2 Windows keys.
I have seen plenty of keyboards with the right-key (menu-key) labeled as a 2nd Windows-key.
Seems such keyboards do exist, but I honestly didn't know that.
I didn't pay enough attention to the picture. My bad.

Comment: Maybe on your machine. My right Windows key opens the start menu and operates shortcuts in exactly the same way as the left Windows key.

Comment: @Tonny Sounds like you're confusing the right Windows key with the [Context/Apps key](http://superuser.com/questions/885043/where-is-the-apps-key-on-a-standard-microsoft-keyboard).

Comment: You're confusing Windows key with the [menu key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key).

Comment: This answer ought to be edited to get to a state as if written today (and without "Edit", "Update" or similar - that is what the revision history is for). Or deleted.

Comment: It depends. Some have both the context key and the right Windows key (e.g., Microsoft "[Natural Keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Natural_keyboard#Natural_Keyboard)" (e.g., model number E03786V105. Mid 1990s) and [Rapoo V700 RGB](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2021/12/24/rapoo-mechanical-keyboards-gotchas-and-setup/)). Some have an 'Fn' and one of the two keys are missing. Of those, it may be configurable which one is included and which is missing (e.g., on -

Comment: cont' - the [Ducky Shine 7](https://www.duckychannel.com.tw/upload/2019_06_052/201906051349143vzt77cMb1.pdf) (page 25) it is configurable with DIP switches. The factory default is the Win key left in. I have set mine to *DIP switch 2* ON (context menu left in) as that is far more useful.)

Comment: Cooler Master's [CK550 V2](https://www.coolermaster.com/catalog/peripheral/keyboards/ck550-v2/) has left out the context key. But it is possible to change it by remapping the Windows key to the corresponding context key action (either by a direct remapping or a macro (only macros are easily copied from keyboard to keyboard)). Though it will be in the wrong physical position (muscle memory problems)—the *Fn* key is where the context key normally is.

Comment: On the [Nedis / Coatyss](https://support.nedis.com/en-us/products/550707541) (model GKBD400BKND) it is the opposite: the context menu is left in (a more sensible choice).